# basic claim about composite function limit.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, logic

is it always true that if $$\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=b$$
then $$\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(f(x))= \lim\limits_{f(x) \to b}g(f(x))$$
given there is no variables outside of f(x) inside g(x)?
is it acceptable saying "the condition ${x \to a}$ is equivalent to ${f(x) \to b}$"?
whether its true or false please explain, simple words if possible,
thanks a lot, hope you understand my english and math language /=

Answer (score 0):

Firstly let me state definition of limit: If for $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta > 0$, such that for $\forall x, 0<|x-a|<\delta $ holds $|f(x)-b|<\epsilon $, then we say, that $b$ is limit of $f$ in point $a$ and wrote $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=b$. Sometimes as shorthand for this definition is used sentence "$f$ tends to $b$, when $x$ tends to $a$" or "$f(x) \to b$ for $x \to a$", but it is good to remember, that such type of sentences are only designation for definition.

Set $U_\delta(a)=\{x: 0<|x-a|<\delta  \}$ is called [punctured neighbourhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)#Deleted_neighbourhood) or deleted neighbourhood of $a$.

There is well known theorem for limit of composition:

Suppose exists $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=b$ and $\lim\limits_{y \to b} F(y)$ and suppose that for $f$ in some punctured neighbourhood of $a$ holds $f(x)\ne b$. Then exists limit of composition $F \circ f$ and holds $\lim\limits_{y \to b} F(y)=\lim\limits_{x \to a} F(f(x))$.

With some extra conditions there is possible to state, also, equivalence of limits: suppose $f$ is invertible or one-to-one function on some punctured neighbourhood of $a$ and mapped it on some punctured neighbourhood of $b$, so, that $f(x) \ne b$ and $f^{-1}(y) \ne a$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=b$ and $\lim\limits_{y \to b} f^{-1}(y)=a$. Then for $F$ defined on punctured neighbourhood of $b$ existence of limit $\lim\limits_{y \to b} F(y)$ is equivalent to  existence of limit $\lim\limits_{x \to a} F(f(x))$ and they are equal in case of existence.